# ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token) using cElementTree

Tags: python, parsing, elementtree

I receive xml strings from an external source that can contains unsanitized user contributed content.

The following xml string gave a ParseError in `cElementTree`:

```
>>> print repr(s)
'<Comment>dddddddd\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08_____</Comment>'
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> ET.XML(s)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ET.XML(s)
  File "<string>", line 106, in XML
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 17
```

Is there a way to make cElementTree not complain?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems to complain about `\x08` you will need to escape that.

**Edit:**

Or you can have the parser ignore the errors using `recover`

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
etree.fromstring(xmlstring, parser=parser)
```

Comment: I don't want to change anything about the content of the XML I receive, I just need to transform it into an `cElementTree Element`.

Comment: escaping is not the same as changing btw.

Comment: the `recover` it no longer available for ElementTrees `XMLParser`, right? Or whats 'lxml'? It's not vanilla python?

Answer (score 29):

I was having the same error (with ElementTree). In my case it was because of encodings, and I was able to solve it without having to use an external library. Hope this helps other people finding this question based on the title. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9209547/2697658))

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ET.fromstring(xmlstring, parser=parser)
```

**EDIT**: Based on comments, this answer might be outdated. But this did work back when it was answered...

Comment: I don't believe that is correct, [`fromstring` doesn't take any arguments apart from text (it does not accept parser)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring). Perhaps you meant [`XML` instead of `fromstring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XML)?

Comment: `parse` function has `parser` attribute, thus you can give it a file name as input instead of string: `e = ElementTree.parse(my_file, parser=ElementTree.XMLParser(encoding='iso-8859-5')
)`

Comment: As mentioned by the first comment, `fromstring` doesn't accept the parser argument. This answer is wrong in syntax.

Comment: The docs suggests `ET.fromstringlist([xmlstring], parser=parser)` could be used to achieve what is intended here.

Answer (score 9):

This code snippet worked for me. I have an issue with the parsing batch of XML files. I had to encode them to 'iso-8859-5'

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(filename, parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding = 'iso-8859-5'))
```

Comment: This worked for me, too, I wonder, why.

Answer (score 7):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110103/113195) to another question and the [according part](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) of the XML spec.

The backspace [U+0008](http://codepoints.net/U+0008) is an invalid character in XML documents. It must be represented as escaped entity `&#8;` and cannot occur plainly.

If you need to process this XML snippet, you must replace `\x08` in `s` before feeding it into an XML parser.

Answer (score 7):

None of the above fixes worked for me. The only thing that worked was to use `BeautifulSoup` instead of `ElementTree` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("data/myfile.xml") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'xml')
```

Then you can search the tree as:

```
soup.find_all('mytag')
```

Comment: There is no '`xml` parser from `BeautifulSoup`'. When you provide the `xml` parameter to `BeautifulSoup`, [it uses `lxml`'s XML parser under the hood.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Comment: @BioGeek thanks, yes I meant you require to install `lxml` before being able to use BeautifulSoup this way. At least in my case I had to install that separately...

Answer (score 5):

After lots of searching through the entire WWW, I only found out that you have to escape certain characters if you want your XML parser to work! Here's how I did it and worked for me:

```
escape_illegal_xml_characters = lambda x: re.sub(u'[\x00-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1F\uD800-\uDFFF\uFFFE\uFFFF]', '', x)
```

And use it like you'd normally do:

```
ET.XML(escape_illegal_xml_characters(my_xml_string)) #instead of ET.XML(my_xml_string)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is most probably an encoding error. For example I had an xml file encoded in UTF-8-BOM (checked from the Notepad++ Encoding menu) and got similar error message.

The workaround (Python 3.6)

```
import io
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

with io.open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(contents)
```

Check the encoding of your xml file. If it is using different encoding, change the 'utf-8-sig' accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

A solution for gottcha for me, using Python's ElementTree... this has the invalid token error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = u"""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<osm generator="pycrocosm server" version="0.6"><changeset created_at="2017-09-06T19:26:50.302136+00:00" id="273" max_lat="0.0" max_lon="0.0" min_lat="0.0" min_lon="0.0" open="true" uid="345" user="john"><tag k="test" v="Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю" /><tag k="foo" v="bar" /><discussion><comment data="2015-01-01T18:56:48Z" uid="1841" user="metaodi"><text>Did you verify those street names?</text></comment></discussion></changeset></osm>"""

xmltest = ET.fromstring(xml.encode("utf-8"))
```

However, it works with the addition of a hyphen in the encoding type:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

Most odd. [Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20526524/4288232) found this footnote in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#id3):

> The encoding string included in XML output should conform to the
>   appropriate standards. For example, “UTF-8” is valid, but “UTF8” is
>   not.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got the same error. (using Element Tree)

I had to add these lines:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    from lxml import etree

    parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True,encoding='utf-8')
    xml_file = ET.parse(path_xml,parser=parser)
```

Works in pyhton 3.10.2

Comment: this works great, with only minimal code changes coming from xml.etree

Answer (score 1):

I have been in stuck with similar problem. Finally figured out the what was the root cause in my particular case. If you read the data from multiple XML files that lie in same folder you will parse also .DS_Store file.
Before parsing add this condition

```
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xml'):
       run_your_code...
```

This trick helped me as well

Answer (score 1):

lxml solved the issue, in my case

```
from lxml import etree

for _, elein etree.iterparse(xml_file, tag='tag_i_wanted', unicode='utf-8'):
    print(ele.tag, ele.text)
```

in another case,

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = etree.parse(xml_file, parser=parser)
tags_needed = tree.iter('TAG NAME')
```

Thanks to [theeastcoastwest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54228063/1693901)

Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with that error was Juan's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20204635/4433222
But wasn't enough - after struggling I found out that an XML file needs to be saved with UTF-8 without BOM encoding.

The solution wasn't working for "normal" UTF-8.

Comment: And what argument do you pass for that?

Comment: oh, it was such a long time ago. don't remember actually, but probably I just saved a file properly in notepad++

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is I had to add mode and encoding while opening the file like below:

```
with open(filenames[0], mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
     readFile()
```

Otherwise it was failing every time with invalid token error if I simply do this:

```
 f = open(filenames[0], 'r')
 readFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

this error is coming while you are giving a link . but first you have to find the string of that link

- response = requests.get(Link)
  root = cElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I tried the other solutions in the answers here but had no luck. Since I only needed to extract the value from a single xml node I gave in and wrote my function to do so:

```
def ParseXmlTagContents(source, tag, tagContentsRegex):
    openTagString = "<"+tag+">"
    closeTagString = "</"+tag+">"
    found = re.search(openTagString + tagContentsRegex + closeTagString, source)
    if found:   
        start = found.regs[0][0]
        end = found.regs[0][1]
        return source[start+len(openTagString):end-len(closeTagString)]
    return ""
```

Example usage would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<parentNode>
    <childNode>123</childNode>
</parentNode>

ParseXmlTagContents(xmlString, "childNode", "[0-9]+")
```