# How to make Python's ElementTree ignore lack of spaces between quotes and attributes?

Tags: python, elementtree

When I run

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.fromstring('<foo bar=""baz=""></foo>')
```

I get

> `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError`: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 11

This is due to the lack of space between `""` and `baz`.

I'm encountering this problem in XML files provided to me by a third party.

Is there any way to make `ElementTree` be a little less pedantic about the spacing and parse it as if there was a space?

Comment: It's worth noting that the solutions present in this similar question will ignore the error, but will not recover the baz attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046240/parseerror-not-well-formed-invalid-token-using-celementtree

Comment: I don't think this is possible. XML is "pedantic" by design. What you have is not XML, and a conformant parser is correct in rejecting it.

Comment: If I just regex this problem, would I have 0 problems afterward? or 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like a solution may not be withing sight...

Until a better solution comes along, here's a hacky workaround for the next poor soul...

```
def xml_fixup(s):  # give it the XML as a tring
    flags = re.DOTALL
    pat_quotes = '\"[^\"]*\"|\'[^\']*\''
    re_quotes = re.compile('(%s)([^>\\s])' % pat_quotes, flags)  # TODO: cache
    re_pieces = re.compile('([^<]+)|(<)((?:[^\"\'>]+|%s)*)(>)' % pat_quotes, flags)  # TODO: cache
    pieces = re_pieces.findall(s)
    return s[:0].join(map(lambda m: m[0] or m[1] + re_quotes.sub('\\1 \\2', m[2]) + m[3], pieces))

print(xml_fixup('<foo bar=""baz=""></foo>'))  # <foo bar="" baz=""></foo>
```

Brownie points if you spot bugs in this!

Comment: it breaks correct attributes:
print(xml_fixup('<foo bar="a" baz="b"></foo>'))
>> <foo bar="a" baz=" b"></foo>