# Why is parsing an XML file going wrong?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML reader application who reads through thousands of XML files, during the processing I received the following error:
`xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 62, column 48`

After debugging I found out its `file_348.xml` which is presented in below code. Now I don't know what's wrong with this XML file, when I open it manually I receive the same error. Is it a corrupt error? What I want is my application to ignore these kind of bad XML files and go on with the ones that are readable. If you have any other workarounds I Would like to hear them

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = 'C:/data/UserA/Desktop//XML-files/file_348.xml'

tree = ET.parse(path)

print(tree)
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046240/parseerror-not-well-formed-invalid-token-using-celementtree

Comment: You can attempt to parse the file in a *try/except* construct and just *pass* if an exception is raised to ignore it

Comment: @ Linux Geek Already tried that but the recover variable is not longer usable for `ET.parse()`

Comment: Perhaps you could show that code and someone will be able to help you

Comment: Looks like `file_348.xml` is not a valid xml doc. Can you share it?

Comment: @BrutusForcus, thats what I did. thank you bro.

Comment: @Andalusia I wasn't clear. My mistake. What I meant was... show the XML data

Comment: @BrutusForcus I meant to say that the try/except thing solved my problem bro. I cant show any XML data because its classified :(